# C++, Linux, system("read ...") causes error

Tags: c++, linux, system

I had a problem and solved it, but there is one issue which should be solved.
I use Windows at work and I use Linux at home. I would like to adapt

```
system("pause");
```

from Windows to Linux.
So I tried
`system("read -n1 -r -p \"press any key\"");`

But every combination including "read" causes at executing the program the error
**h: 1: read: Illegal option -n**
Now I use

```
printf("press enter\”):
getchar();
```

but I would like to know why system("read ...") causes this error. If I type
**read -n1 -r p "press any key"**
it works without problems.
Is there any secret? Why is it so difficult to find an equivalent code for
`system("pause");`

in Linux.
Any help is appreciated.

Andreas

I tried system("read -ns1"); but the error did not disappear. I searched in stackoverflow.com and got a solution but I want to know why "read" in combination with "system" causes an error which I do not understand.

Comment: Don't use `system()` *ever*. It's a security nightmare and there are better ways to achieve what you are trying to do.

Comment: The `-n` option is a `bash` extension. `system()` uses `sh`, which doesn't have that option.

Comment: The `getchar` approach is miles better than having `system` spin up another process just to waste time. Obviously performance isn't a concern here, pretty much anything you can do on a computer is faster than waiting for a human to hit a button, but the extravagance irks me all the same.

Comment: "Why is it so difficult to find an equivalent code for system("pause");" because `system` by its very nature depends on the OS

Answer (score 0):

Because `read` is a shell builtin not a command

```
type read
read is a shell builtin
```

The best you can do is to avoid `system` and read in C++, with any of the available options, however, if you really, really want to go that way

```
system("bash -c \"read -n1 -r -p 'press any key'\");
```